# Constrain member function template in class template with inner type same as class template type

Tags: c++, templates, c++98

I want a member function that more or less does the same thing as this:

```
template<class T, template<class T> class U>
void f(const U<T>& x)
{
 ...
}
```

...but in a template class already parameterized on `T`:

```
template<class T>
class A
{
    ???
    // maybe template< template<class T> class U>
    // maybe template< class U<T> >
    void f(const U<T>& x)
    {
     ...
    }
}
```

This might be doable using type aliases (with `using`), but this is an older C++98 codebase, so I can't try that route.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `T` inside the member function template when deducing the argument:

```
template<class T>
struct A
{
    template<template<class> class U>
    void f(const U<T> & x) {}
};
```

This constrains the function template `f` to only accept arguments that are instantiations of a class on `T`.

```
A<int> a;

S<int> s1;
a.f(s1);  // ok, a and s1 are instantiated over int

a.f(42);  // error, 42 is not a U<T>

S<double> s2;
a.f(s2);  // error, a is instantiated over int,
          // but s2 is instantiated over double
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6q9f8vven).